# Javascript stopping scroll from jumping

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a page where you can click to slideDown an element from the top of the page.

I am trying to create a rule that says if the push down is visible and the screen has scrolled further than the height of the push down then it should be hidden again. Meaning the user will have to push the button to get it to show again.

In my HTML I have:

```
<div class="row" id="learn-more" style="display:none">
  <div class="small-12 columns" id="close">
    <p id="close-learn">
      <i class="fa fa-times pull-right fa-2x"></i>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 columns" id="learn-content">
    <h1>Content for Pushdown</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="hero">
  <div class="small-12 columns small-centered">
    <p id="learn"><a class="transition">Learn More</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my Javascript I have:

```
  // Open and close learn more section
  $("#learn").on("click", function() {
    $("#learn-more").slideDown();
  });

  $("#close-learn").on("click", function() {
    $("#learn-more").slideUp();
  });

  // Close learn-more based on scroll position
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {

    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    if ($("#learn-more").is(":visible") && scrollPosition > $("#learn-more").height()) {
      $("#learn-more").slideUp()
    } 
  });
```

This all works but when the #learn-more element slides up the page jumps down about 500 pixels which is the height of the #learn-more element. I would like mine to work in the same way as [Airbnb's new homepage](http://www.airbnb.com) when you click the 'how it works' button and then scroll below the push down element.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: try scrolling to top using: window.scrollTo(0, 0);

Comment: I had a similar issue. Setting CSS `#learn-more {overflow: hidden;}` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Hey both, thanks for the replies unfortunately neither seem to have fixed the jump. Any others ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this situation occurs because $(window).scrollTop position is preserved after the the slideUp() is called.
But we can memorize the visible position of Learn More button relative to the top of the window and after text block is hidden return to this position. Also, i suggest to use hide() instead of slideUp() here.

Here is what I suggest to do on scroll:

```
 $(window).on("scroll", function(event) {
      var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
      var learnMore = $("#learn-more");
      if (learnMore.is(":visible") && scrollPosition > learnMore.height()) {
             var learnMoreButtonTop = $("#learn").offset().top - scrollPosition;
             learnMore.hide();
             $(window).scrollTop(learnMoreButtonTop);
        } 
  });
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/darevskaya/dq9t5/14/)

Comment: This is perfect. The only part I had to change was learnMore.height() to learnMore.outerHeight() to take account for the padding. Thanks for your help!